# Internet Explorer vs soapui in Web Services Test

Tags: web-services, soapui

I have a web services a wsdl/soap. when i Test it in Internet Explorer it show me the entire xml, but when i test it with soapui it show me an error with log error bad request.

What is the difference to test a wsdl/soap in soapui and Internet Explorer ? thanks for your answer.

and how to fix this error please ? When i try to import my WSDl with soapui i have the error :

S

```
un Jun 05 14:10:37 CEST 2011:ERROR:javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /html): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.
   javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /html): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.checkElementName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlInterfaceDefinition.load(WsdlInterfaceDefinition.java:48)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:66)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:30)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.cacheDefinition(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:264)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.access$400(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:44)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:230)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:140)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Comment: what is this `soapui`? Some iPhone thing?

Comment: No it's not for Phone. http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/getting-started.html.

Comment: When we test in IE, is this to say that the web services is working fine ?

Comment: how do you try to setup the soapUI project? do you provide a URL? If so, can you provide what the URL looks like (I assume it is a local one)

Comment: also, are you able to provide the WSDL and schema definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say test in IE you mean just browse to the WS URL with a ?WSDL at the end ?

If that is the case, then this test will simply display in your browser the XML of the WSDL definition - so as long as the WSDL hosted is valid XML IE will display it fine.

However, when you try to setup a soapUI project to test, it will validate that it is a valid WSDL/XSD (rather than just checking that it is valid XML, e.g all tags are closed correctly etc).

If you need more help understanding what the issue is we would need to see the logs/errors from soapUI.

Comment: if you want help with that - your original question was "What is the difference to test a wsdl/soap in soapui and Internet Explorer" - Which I have hopefully answered above, but if you have other questions or want further advice then we need more details.